# share the database in sharedrive

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a application which front end is HTML and back end is access. I need to place the file in shared drive where my team has access. 
When i change the script file name to share path i am receiving error

> file path is invalid

```js
<script>
function fnadd()
{
    var a=[];
    var myStr = "";
    var con=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var rs=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    con.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    rs.open("select DISTINCT email from test",con,1,3);

    var n=rs.RecordCount;

    while(!rs.eof)
    {
        myStr =myStr+rs('email').value+ ", ";
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
    a = myStr;
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").value = a;
}
</script>
CC: <input type="text" id="textbox_1">
<input type="button" value="view" onclick="fnadd();"/>

<script>
```

Path:
`\\10.145.188.70\09 Star\Star ITO\Service Desk\Operations`
(Or)
`Z:\09 Star\Star ITO\Service Desk\Operations`

Comment: You change script file name *where*?

Comment: con.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    rs.open("select DISTINCT email from test",con,1,3);

Comment: in the open comment i need to change